# The existence of the limit of a composite function

Tags: calculus

I try to solve the following problem: Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $f :A \longrightarrow B, g:B\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two functions. If $a \in A'$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b\in B'$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to b}g(y)$ exists, then the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}(g\circ f)(x)$ exists?

I tried to use a result which states that if $g$ has the limit $l$ in $b$ and $f(x)\not =b, \forall x\not=a$ in a neighbourhood of $a$, then $g\circ f$ has the limit $l$ in $a$. Still, my problem doesn't say nothing about the necessary condition concerning $f$ in the above result. Also, since the problem states only the existence of $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to b}g(y)$, it is possible to have an infinite limit and I'm not so sure that the result works in this case. So my guess is that the limit doesn't exist but I can't find a counterexample. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You want only proof the the limit of the composite function exists, not that it is the same than $lim_{y\to b}g(y)$. Right?

Comment: Which definition of limit are you using? Does it contain a "$0 < d(x,a) < \delta$", or only a  "$d(x,a) < \delta$", i.e. is the value at $a$ [if that is in the domain] ignored, or is it taken into account?

Comment: @ Emilio Novati: Yes, I just want to show the existence/non-existence. @ Daniel Fischer: $d(x,a)<\delta$

Comment: In that case we don't need $f(x) \neq b$ for $x\neq a$. If $a\in A$ and $b \in B$, the assertion is just the continuity of $g\circ f$ at $a$ given that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continuous at $b = f(a)$. If $a, b, l\in \mathbb{R}$, all is direct with the Euclidean metric. If any of these is $\pm \infty$, we need either use a formulation of limits using neighbourhoods rather than distances, or use a metric on $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty,+\infty]$ instead of the Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \frac 1x \in \Bbb Z\\ x & \frac 1x \notin \Bbb Z\end{cases}$$
$$g(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & y = 0\\1 & y \ne 0\end{cases}$$